# Running nginx container with pwd doesn't work in bash but adding the complete location in powershell worls

Tags: bash, docker, nginx

I have index.html file in a folder. I am mapping the local directory into the nginx docker container.

When I run the nginx docker container using the command

```
docker run --name website -v  C:\Users\prash\Documents\Programming\Spring\Docker:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
```

The container starts successfully but when I run the following two commands in bash, although the container starts, I can't open index.html file in browser.

```
docker run --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
```

What might be the issue here?

I am new to docker, I tried finding the solution for this, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is your current directory when you run the 2nd command?

Comment: If you just run the `pwd` command by itself, what does it print?

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows. `$(pwd)` is a Linux shell feature that doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: @HansKilian I am using bash for windows. I am in the same directory as I have my idex.html file. Running the pwd from the folder I was in prints the following:



`$ pwd
/c/Users/prash/Documents/Programming/Spring/Docker`

Comment: It might be the `/c/Users/...` notation rather than `C:\Users\...` then. Does `docker run --name website -v  /c/Users/prash/Documents/Programming/Spring/Docker:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest` work?

Comment: It was because of the notation, thanks @HansKilian 
I used the followiung command and it worked fine
`docker run --name website -v  C:/Users/prash/Documents/Programming/Spring/Docker:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:8
0 nginx:latest`